# Using auto for iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I have the following code:

```
template<typename ty>
bool vector_has(const std::vector<ty> &in_vector, const ty element) {
  for(auto it = std::cbegin(in_vector); it != std::cend(in_vector); it++) 
    if(*it == element) return true;
  return false;
}
```

I have given the `it` type of `auto`. Visual Studio seems not to know what that is (before run)... What is the type of `it`?

Comment: The type of `it` is the same as the return type of `std::cbegin(in_vector)`. That's the whole point of `auto`. Why do you ask?

Comment: I got into confusion when I tried to write `std::vector<ty>::` and nothing showed up from IntelliSense. That's why I am asking. It might seem a stupid question, but this is the only place I though of to be the best for asking this.

Comment: Don't rely on IntelliSense. Read the documentation when you want to be sure.

Comment: This is what I'll be doing from now on. Thank you

Comment: You took the vector by const reference, so `cbegin` is redundant over `begin`. And your loop reinvents `std::find`.

Comment: Yes, I know what I am doing there, but I had some trouble with `std::find`, so I wanted to have this.

Comment: @Victor, don't rely on intellisense. C++ is notoriously difficult to parse. It has a context-dependent grammar and because of this, it takes a disproportionately large amount of effort to provide accurate autocompletion functionality (or a decent compiler for that matter). Autocompletion/intellisense/semantic data as you type, has started being good, only in the last years for C++. There are still situations in Visual Studio (and XCode and Netbeans/C++) where you have correct code, but code metadata is not up to date/not generated. Don't consider Intellisense an authoritative source.

Comment: Keep in mind that even theoretically it can be impossible for Intellisense to display to you the correct type, because the same file may be included differently in other files, resulting in different definitions -- and in such cases whichever one it should you will be incorrect at least half the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it` has the type `std::vector<ty>::const_iterator` which is deduced from the return type of `std::cbegin(std::vector<ty>)`.

Comment: It's deduced from the type of `std::cbegin()`, which actually calls `vector::begin()` via `std::begin()`.

Comment: @T.C. Do you say my answer is wrong? If so, can you give me more detail so I can fix it / edit my answer yourself / answer yourself so I can delete?

Comment: It is a small detail, but `std::vector::cbegin()` is not called. What is called in the question is `std::cbegin(in_vector)`. The return type is the same

Answer (score -1):

`begin` and `cbegin` will yield the same kind of iterator for a const vector as input.

On the other side, I think you should use the range-based for loop,
since it is less verbose:

```
template<typename ty>
bool vector_has(const std::vector<ty> &in_vector, const ty element) {
  for(auto const & val : in_vector) 
    if(val == element) return true;
      return false;
}
```

P.S.: I also recommend that you pass `element` by const reference to avoid copies: `const tv & element`.

Comment: "std::vector<ty>::iterator and std::vector<ty>::const_iterator will be the same type " No, they are not.

Comment: T.C. is right. The types `std::vector<ty>::iterator` and `std::vector<ty>::const_iterator` do not change for a `const std::vector` vs a `std::vector`. The version of `begin` that gets used is what changes...

Comment: Corrected the mistake. Thanks.